# KNP Menu Bundle Translation Domain

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

I'm using **Symfony 2.3** and the **KnpMenuBundle**.

Is it possible to use a **translation domain** for menu items?

Like this:

```
$menu['management']->addChild(
    'msg.user.list',
    array(
        'route' => 'user_list',
        'translation_domain' => 'navigation'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 6):

1. According to the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/i18n.html) and [KnpMenuBundle documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/v2.1.1/Resources/doc/i18n.rst),you may set the translation domain (`menu` in my snippets), while adding menu items in your `MenuBuilder` class:

   ```
   $menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => 'homepage'))
        ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'menu');
   ```
2. You may better want to add the translation domain into the whole menu instead:

   ```
   $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root')
                ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'menu');
   ```
3. Then create a file named `knp_menu.html.twig` in:

   ```
   app/Resources/views/menu/
   ```
4. and put this in it:

   ```
   {% extends 'knp_menu.html.twig' %}

   {% block label %}
       {% if options.allow_safe_labels and item.getExtra('safe_label', false) %}
           {{ item.label | raw | trans(item.getExtra('translation_params', {}), item.getExtra('translation_domain', 'menu'))}}
       {% else %}
           {{ item.label | trans(item.getExtra('translation_params', {}), item.getExtra('translation_domain', 'menu')) }}
       {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}
   ```

   (If the file already exists, just replace the `{% block label %}{% endblock %}` part)
5. Be carefull to have translation files (`.xliff` or whatever) naming strategy like:

   ```
   {translation_domain}.{locale}.{extenstion}
   ```

   for example:

   ```
   menu.fa.xliff
   ```

   In this path:

   ```
   app/Resources/translations/
   ```
6. The last part is:

   ```
   # app/config/config.yml
   knp_menu:
       twig:
           template: knp_menu.html.twig
   ```
7. Up-Vote this nice tutorial.
8. Have fun!